# WGET : how to download a link and sub link?

Tags: wget

I use `WGET` to download the data on the website and I save it as an HTML file. Data is presented in tabular form . The table consists of three columns are id_sales , sales_name, number_of_buyers . if the numbers in the number_of_the buyer column clicked , will display detailed data . I want to download the data in the form tables and data details. to be able to see the data, I have to log in first.

[image]

**My Script :**

```
@echo off

SET office_id=613
set userid=123456
set password=p@ssw0rd

set save_cookies="cookies\cookies.txt"
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" --post-data="username=%userid%&password=%password%&sublogin=Login" --save-cookies=%save_cookies% --keep-session-cookies http://app/login/login/loging_simpel

wget  --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" -r -E -nd --load-cookies=cookies\cookies.txt --save-cookies=cookies\cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies "http://app/portal/credit/result.php?office_id=613&years=2013"

pause
```

The above script could just download the data table only. but the details are not downloaded. please help me to correct this script . thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Lynx or links could be used to transform html table into text but ideally I would suggest investing in writing this with [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)